# What is an worker thread in Visual Studio and can my C++ Application Exploit it?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

While debugging my C++ application through Visual Studio 2010 I happened to see these worker thread below main thread.[image: Debugging Window]

Now I know that recently in C++11 there is support for multithreading but this is not C++11 code and it doesnt use any third party threading library aslo. After googling I found this definition of worker thread from Microsoft website

> A worker thread is commonly used to handle background tasks that the user should not have to wait for to continue using your application. Tasks such as recalculation and background printing are good examples of worker threads.

Now my question is why are the worker threads present, are they created by Visual Studio to improve my applications performace.  Can I myself write such application which will exploit these functionality provided by the complier ?

Comment: Did you read the rest of [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69644x60.aspx) you quoted from?  It provides all of the information needed to create threads in MFC, and if you're not using MFC then you probably want to [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6h8hye8.aspx).

Comment: @RetiredNinja this code aint using MFC and and I dont want to write an multithreaded application. I wanted to know why these threads are generated.

Comment: You asked if you can write an application that exploits this functionality.  That sounds like a multithreaded application to me.  In the picture you showed it would appear those threads were created by Teamcenter.  They were created using the `_beginthreadex` Windows API function described in the links I posted.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok now I got that the threads are created by **_beginthreadx** Windows API but I dont see a respective header file included for the same in the code file.

Comment: @RetiredNinja by the way are these threads from MFC or are Win32 threads.

Answer (score 0):

When I consider BackgroundWorker threads in .NET framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker), I think the keypoint is the event mechanism. A worker thread is used for (as MSDN says) background tasks which should be seperated for example GUI thread in order to prevent freeezes. You can create and use your own worket thread class, but as I said before BackgroundWorker has already defined events and you can use them in order to detect start of thread (DoWork), update and completion of your task assigned to the thread. Multithreading is almost unavoidable when you are doing something other than GUI operations (reading rom a file and etc.). Of course, examples are not limited to GUI development, but this is one of the most common scenarios you can see. In summary, instead of developing your own worker thread implementation, why don't you use BackgroundWorker which has a nice and tested event support and etc.

Comment: I have read the same example over the Internet and from the code file I have confirmed it doesnt uses any thread related header. I want to know why these thread are generated.

Comment: I think these threads had been created and used by third party framework/library (may be CORBA or something similar) that your code depends. May be you did not create them explicitly, but somehow dependent code (underlying framework/library) created them implicitly in order to do its task. If you did not create them, then there is no harm and also nothing much to do other than trusting the underlying framework/library.

Comment: Ok this helps a little that we are using SOA calls which depends on CORBA architecture in the application.